# Is there any way to assign diffrent type variables in single statement..?

Tags: c#

I am thinking is there any way to assign different type of variables in single statement..?

```
string s = "";
int ia = 0;
int ib = 5;

// is there any short hand technique to assign all 
// 3 variables in single statement..?:
s =  ia = ib;
```

Comment: No. you can't mix up different types

Comment: Not directly. And if there was, it would look confusing and probably violate about every coding standard I know. Please write code that's well readable. It does not matter how long it is, we all have scrollbars.

Comment: `s=(ia=ib).ToString();`

Comment: @ PetSerAl, seems a solution.

Comment: What's the problem you want to solve? Consider code clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string s = "";
int ia = 0;
int ib = 5;
s = (ia = ib).ToString();
```

I wouldn't recommend it, but it will work - `ia` will be 5, and `s` will be "5".

Would you *really* rather do that than use two statements though? I try to avoid doing too much in a single statement - brevity is *not* the same thing as clarity. I think most people would find this simpler to read:

```
string s = "";
int ia = 0;
int ib = 5;
ia = ib;
s = ib.ToString();
```

Or better yet:

```
int ib = 5;
int ia = ib;
string s = ib.ToString();
```

(I dislike initializing variables with values which are just going to be overwritten without ever being read.)

Comment: yea, its a way of doing this s=(ia=ib).ToString();

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni: I'm not sure how to interpret your comment... that's the same code that's in my answer, and I've suggested that it's generally a bad idea in terms of readability.

Comment: yea, its a bad idea, but I have asked a way for doing this, and yes it is a way, may be bad in terms of readability, but we can do this.

Answer (score 2):

You *can*, but you have to explain (via *operator*) how to do it:

```
  public class MyClass {
    public static implicit operator MyClass(int value) {
      return new MyClass();
    }
  }

  ...

  int a = 2;
  int b = 3;

  MyClass c = a = b;
```

In your case `int` can't be *implicitly converted* into `String` and that is the cause of the error. The solution is an *explicit conversion*:

```
  int a = 2;
  int b = 3;

  String c = (a = b).ToString(); // explicit conversion required
```

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can convert types. In you're case by example:

```
int a1 = 5;
String s = "" + a1;
```

It's not the best way. But the simplest.

Comment: It's say that calling `ToString()` is simpler than introducing string concatenation for no reason.

Answer (score -1):

You can use shorthand technique, if datatype is same. In your case...

```
int ia = 0, ib = 5;
string s = ia = ib;
```

Comment: Did you try that yourself?

Comment: int ia = 0, ib = 5; This part ofcourse works. Regarding the 2nd part you can't assign int to string. Sorry I didn't payed much attention on that part.

Comment: Actual question is regarding assign different type variables

Comment: My bad, sorry. I didn't noticed.